# funk-fueled -- what exactly does this term mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Celine Dion Performs Edith Piaf Classic in Tribute to Paris](https://www.yahoo.com/music/celine-dion-performs-edith-piaf-classic-in-tribute-043116123.html)

Example:

> The display brought tears to the eyes of many. Others stood stoically and watched, temporarily taken away from the celebration of the event. Some couples held their spouse or significant other tightly as they ruminated over the terror attacks that killed 129 people at various locations around Paris, including 89 fans at the Bataclan concert hall who were attending a show by the **funk-fueled** alternative rock band Eagles of Death Metal.

What exactly does this term mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Fuel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fuel?q=fueled#fuel__10) as a verb means:

> Supply or power (an industrial plant, vehicle, or machine) with fuel: *power stations **fueled by** low-grade coal*.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

[Funk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/funk) is a kind of music:

> music that combines elements of rhythm and blues and soul music and
>   that is characterized by ***a percussive vocal style, static harmonies,
>   and a strong bass line with heavy downbeats***

[Merriam-Webster]

***Funk-fueled*** in the sentence means the alternative rock music was *characterized, powered, or influenced* by a ***funky*** music style.

Edit: ***Fuel*** has  *always* been used metaphorically unless used for vehicles, planes, power generators, etc. Please refer to the 1.3 meaning of its noun definition.

Comment: These guys could be said to have been "funk-fueled" - even to have defined the concept: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSNNryOhReA

Comment: Since you picked the literal definition of fuel (rather than, for instance, the third definition on that page), it might be helpful to explain that "fuel" is often used metaphorically, and that indeed its use is metaphorical here.

Comment: @KyleStrand Thanks for your comment. Fuel is "always" used metaphorically unless used for transportation vehicles, planes, etc. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Rathony I wouldn't say that's exactly true; food, for instance, is *literally* fuel for your body. Also, I believe you mean `*always*` (i.e., using *italics* for emphasis, or possibly **bold**) rather than `"always"` (i.e. scare quotes). (Sorry to nitpick, but unintentional scare quotes are a pet peeve of mine.)

Comment: @KyleStrand You are using ***fuel*** metaphorically for food for your body. It came from Old French that meant ***material for burning*** like firewood. It has never been part of our food.

Comment: @Rathony Fuel just needs to store chemical energy, released via combustion. The metabolic process is a slow form of combustion. It's actually *more* of a stretch to refer to fuel for a nuclear reaction (e.g. in a nuclear power plant) as "fuel", since it's not technically "burned" to release chemical energy.

Comment: @KyleStrand I know exactly what you mean. The word didn't originate from the food we eat. It evolved and expanded its meaning. Fuel meant what it meant at the beginning. As you said it is a stretch.

Comment: @Rathony You can't use etymology to derive the "true" meaning of a word in contemporary English, and even if you could, my point about metabolism is that food is *still* fuel by that definition, since it is *literally* "material for burning."

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, the term "funk-fueled" means the band is influenced by funk, it is driven by it, it is shown in their music.